# What is the Powerpoint Graphics ribbon and how can I make my own?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, office365

I can't seem to find anything when I search for this so here goes: I got a Powerpoint presentation sent to me from a colleague. In it he used a shape that I thought was pretty neat. When I clicked on it I don't get the "Shape Format" ribbon like you usually do, instead I got a "Graphics Format" ribbon:

[image]

This seems to be some form of grouping of objects but it's not using the Group function. If I use Group on several objects, all whitespace between the objects are filled when I use Shape Fill, but when I select Graphics Fill or Graphics Outline here it changes each individual "object" of the group instead. I asked him how he did it and he just said he picked it up from another presentation but didn't remember where or who had made the original.

Searching for this online only results in guides on how to make generic background images or similar. Does anyone know what this Graphics thing in Powerpoint is and how it can be used? I can't even seem to find results in the Microsoft documentation either. Does anyone know how I can make use of these or where I can find more information on them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

The "**Graphics**" is the name given to **Vector** images, more specifically, `.svg` images, in PowerPoint. The `.svg` images is essentially a group of shapes and sometimes include text and raster images, too. In other words, the image you think is pretty neat is a `.svg` image. When you'll click on the `Convert to Shape` button, PowerPoint will split the vector into shapes, which can then be edited with the "Shape Format" ribbon.

Additional links: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/edit-svg-images-in-microsoft-office-365-69f29d39-194a-4072-8c35-dbe5e7ea528c#BKMK_Convert

Comment: Ah, this makes sense, thank you for the answer and additional resources!

Comment: Not entirely correct:  it's not a matter of vector graphics or not; the Graphics tab appears specifically when the selected shape is an SVG graphic (either inserted SVG file, inserted Icon or anything else that's been added via PasteSpecial | as SVG.  This is available in PowerPoint 2019 as well, so it's not restricted to Office 365, the subscription version.  Also, SVGs are not necessarily vector-only. An SVG can contain nothing but a raster image but still show the Graphics tab when selected. If you ungroup it, you then get the Picture tab, as you'd expect of a purely raster graphic.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, hmm, you're right, when I wrote "Vector", I meant to say `.svg`s. As for whether it's available for Office 2019, the link I attached says that it's only available for 365. only.

Comment: It only mentions 365 at the top ... until you click the "more" link to see the vast array of other versions:  Excel for Microsoft 365 Word for Microsoft 365 Outlook for Microsoft 365 PowerPoint for Microsoft 365 Excel for Microsoft 365 for Mac Word for Microsoft 365 for Mac PowerPoint for Microsoft 365 for Mac PowerPoint for the web Excel 2021 Word 2021 Outlook 2021 PowerPoint 2021 Excel 2021 for Mac Word 2021 for Mac PowerPoint 2021 for Mac Excel 2019 Word 2019 Outlook 2019 PowerPoint 2019 Excel 2019 ... and on and on. WAY more than the character limit here permits. :-)

Comment: Right @SteveRindsberg. I'll just delete that line.

Comment: @SaaranshGarg Thanks. And thanks, Tanaka-san, for asking an interesting question, something we all learned a bit from.